# Operational Calculus: $\left ( 1-D \right )^{-1} x^3$ expanded as the geometric series $\left ( 1+D+D^2+D^3+\cdot \cdot \cdot \right )x^3$

Tags: calculus, operator-theory, geometric-series

While watching a YouTube video by Supware, titled "The Abstract World of Operational Calculus", the speaker is working with the derivative operator $D$. He says he will "formally" expand
$(1-D)^{-1} x^3$ as a geometric series, and proceeds to replace it with $$\left ( 1+D+D^2+D^3+\cdot \cdot \cdot  \right )x^3$$

Could someone please explain how he did it? I have no expertise in this area at all, so I'm not sure how he did that.

Comment: Basic idea is that an infinite geometric sum $1+x+x^2+\dotsb=\frac{1}{1-x}$, or we can say that $(1+x+x^2+\dotsb)(1-x)=1$. This means the multiplicative inverse of $(1-x)$ can be represented by this series. Now this can be used to formally describe $(1-D)^{-1}$

Comment: How could I not see that haha... thanks a lot!!

Comment: I think you’re missing the linear term in the formal expansion, i.e., it should be $1+D+D^2+D^3+\cdots$.